# How do I get to BIOS from the "Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported." screen?

Tags: grub2

I know that you are supposed to type exit or something, but my keyboard is not responsive, but does light up. Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: Rebooting with Ctrl-Alt-Del and pressing keys like Delete, F8, and Insert a lot is the usual approach.